# Arduino Uno Doesn't show up under Serial Ports, but it does show up in Device Manager

Tags: arduino

My Arduino Uno doesn't show up under Serial Ports in the Arduino IDE, but it does show up in Device Manager.

I have a I2C Sainsmart LCD connected to the Arduino.

Do you have any idea why it would do this?

Comment: It works now, but it sometimes does this again.

Comment: Could someone help me stop this?

Comment: What are you doing that's different when it does show up compared to when it doesn't show up?

Comment: Im doing nothing.

Comment: This is a user-level question, not about electronics.  Go ask someplace arduinees are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens from time to time.

What can you do?

1- Try unplugging the USB and plug again.

If 1 didn't work.

2- Go to task manager> Processes> find the Arduino IDE that is already running> Right click> End Process tree> unplug the USB> run the IDE again.

Works every time for me.

Comment: I did both of those things

Comment: Are you connecting any serial devices to the hardware serial on the Arduino uno specifically pins (0,1)?

Comment: no, i'm not connecting it to 1 and 0

Answer (score 0):

Simply go into device manager, uninstall the driver from the port the Arduino was (e.g COM3)
and the Arduino will show as an unknown device in the device manager list. Browse into the Arduino (installation directory)\drivers, next, that's it.

This happened to me a few times and my Arduino wouldn't sync, after finding out that sometimes Windows assigns some driver it thinks is best to that port, I did the procedure above and it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the unknown device then restart the PC and install the driver again. You will see a new port name for example COM6, COM3 etc. Then open the Arduino IDE and select your port from tools and it will work.